# Login app using fingerprint instead of password

Tags: flutter, dart

I am working on Flutter login screen but I want to register app using a fingerprint instead of the password. We have local_auth in Flutter but that is fore unlocking app using a fingerprint or touch id. What are the available methods to do that?

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://medium.com/flutterpub/fingerprint-authentication-in-flutter-8fc14455c8a9)

Answer (score 2):

What you can do is to refer the plugin local_auth available on Pub and authenticate with local authentication. It is the fastest way to handle it. The package is maintained by the official flutter team, so no need to worry about the updates.

Check the repository and examples here:

https://github.com/flutter/plugins/tree/master/packages/local_auth

Thanks.

Comment: I want something like communicating with servers with the fingerprint for signup and login.

Comment: As the package name suggests, it is for "Local" auth. So it does not go to server and compare the finger prints. It uses the mechanism where the fingerprints enrolled on the devices are allowed to go further. In your case, I believe, it will be device specific - it has to match exact hardware. Most of the providers of the hardware have Android API for that. I believe you can do it via flutter - however not sure if it can support iOS.